# URLs with many special characters defined using \urldef

Tags: hyperref, urls

I am attempting to use an `\urldef` defined URL to print as a clickable link. But it's resulting in an error.

So far I have this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\usepackage{url}
\urlstyle{sf}
    \urldef{\myurl}\url{http://wam.org.ae/servlet/Satellite?c=WamLocAnewscid=1289997634568&p=1135099400289&pagename=WAM%2FWamLocAnews%2FW-T-LAN-FullNews}
\begin{document}
\myurl
\end{document}
```

The last lines of the error read

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\hyper@linkurl ...n/S/URI/URI(#2)>>}\Hy@colorlink 
                                              {\@urlcolor }#1\close@pdfl...
l.5 ...ename=WAM%2FWamLocAnews%2FW-T-LAN-FullNews}
```

If anyone can give me some pointers or examples on how I can get it to work, that would be great.

---EDIT----

I understand @egreg's answer should work after I update my TeX installation.

... (later) ...

It did solve it. So if you get the error reported above, you probably have a very old version that needs updating.

Comment: Do you need to display the website URL in the text, or just have a clickable link to the website with some other text?

Comment: Just say `\myurl` if you want a link showing all of the URL.

Comment: It seems `\href` does not work with `\urldef` - the problem is _not_ caused by the special characters in your url.

Comment: @Werner I want to display the full URL as a clickable link to the same URL.

Comment: @MartinSchröder Yes, I expected that this is where the problem lies. Can you suggest an alternative approach to end up with a clickable URL with special charcaters?

Comment: If you just use `\myurl`, as @egreg suggested, the URL is printed and hyperlinked in the resulting PDF, *with* all the special characters.

Comment: @werner I tried that, ending with
`\myurl
\end{document}` but that doesn't work for me. Do you have a minimal working example for me? I am using pdflatex, not sure if that can influence it.

Comment: @user12083: `\url` just works.

Comment: Thanks all for the suggestions. A TeX upgrade should solve it.

Comment: @user12083: Did an update solve your problem?

Comment: @Werner Yes, it did.